# Memória baixa após mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Venho observando que sempre após rodar o mysqldump, a memória livre do servidor fica muito baixa e não é liberada logo em seguida.

O comando que estou usando é

```
mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 --add-drop-table --single-transaction basededados1 > backup.sql
```

Minhas tabelas estão em InnoDB.
Preciso adicionar algum comando para liberar a memória quando acabar o mysqldump?

Comment: Aparenta ser um [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22017) no mysql. Qual é a sua versão do mysql?

Comment: @lazyFox É um RDS na Amazon, versão 5.6.40.
Usar o single-transaction é ok né?

Comment: Esse parâmetro não deverá ter influência, mas para descargo de consciência pode sempre testar com e sem o parâmetro para ver se os resultados oscilam no uso da memória.